# Problems, building a switch case in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to develop something like a switch-case functionality, like knowen from other language, in python 3.7.

For that, I used this tutorial here: https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

and started with this code:

```
class ClassCheckShipping:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __checkAktivweltShipping(self, country):
        return "checkShipping für Aktivwelt"

    def __checkHoerhelferShipping(self, country):
        return "checkShipping für Hörhelfer"

    def checkShipping(self, merchant, country):
        self.country = country
        switcher = {
            "Aktivwelt": __checkAktivweltShipping,
            "Hörhelfer": __checkHoerhelferShipping
        }
        func = switcher.get(merchant, lambda: "unbekannter Merchant")
        print(func())
```

Unfortunately, i get the following error and i can't find my mistake.

> File "M:\Python-Projekte\Wipando-Feeds\CheckShipping.py", line 18, in checkShipping
>       "Aktivwelt": __checkAktivweltShipping,
>   NameError: name '_ClassCheckShipping__checkAktivweltShipping' is not defined

Can you please give me a hint to fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternate solution would be to define `switcher` as a class member (since it's constant) then you can omit to use `self.`

```
def __checkAktivweltShipping(self, country):
    return "checkShipping für Aktivwelt"

def __checkHoerhelferShipping(self, country):
    return "checkShipping für Hörhelfer"

__switcher = {
    "Aktivwelt": __checkAktivweltShipping,
    "Hörhelfer": __checkHoerhelferShipping
}
```

now it must be referenced using `self` too, but the code is simpler (also faster because python doesn't have to rebuild the dictionary at each call, it's only done once, when creating the class)

```
def checkShipping(self, merchant, country):
    self.country = country
    func = self.__switcher.get(merchant, lambda: "unbekannter Merchant")
    print(func())
```

Answer (score 4):

You must add `self` to the methods in `switcher`:

```
switcher = {
    "Aktivwelt": self.__checkAktivweltShipping,
    "Hörhelfer": self.__checkHoerhelferShipping
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should write: `self.__checkAktivweltShipping` and `self.__checkHoerhelferShipping`